# SQL Page View PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have a page view on my PHP pages and Googled this.  I don't want to make a new database for it so I've found an available spot in my database (so can't use any solutions that requires more than 1 cell in the database.

I got this code which counts the visit so that part works fine, but I can't seem to make the number of views to be shown (printed I guess its the right word)

```
<?php  //Adds one to the counter 
  mysql_query("UPDATE news SET post = post + 1, published=published, last_edit=last_edit WHERE id=$id");

//Retrieves the current count 
$count1 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT post FROM post"));  

// Displays the count on your site print

             echo $count1; ?>
```

Any idea why I won't get the result to show?

Comment: Also, in the first query you're updating the `news` table, but in the second you are selecting from the `post` table

Comment: tried to change to this: SELECT post FROM news but still nothing

Comment: Try to `var_dump($count1)` after your `mysql_fetch_row()` line and see what's in it

Comment: returns with result: NULL.

Checked the database and it says 9 tho

Comment: When using my original code (as posted above) i get result bool(false)

Comment: Then your SELECT query doesn't return any rows, you can check that with `var_dump(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT post FROM news")));`

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } 

Any idea what this means?

Changed the code to SELECT post FROM news to get this

Comment: then i get the error above & this: int(68003)

Comment: The `int(68003)` means that you're selecting 68003 rows (because you don't use a WHERE clause in your SELECT query.

The `array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" }` should be your post value (use `$count1[0]` to get "2"), but this isn't the value you're expecting because this is the post value of the first record of all 68003 rows

Comment: added WHERE id=$id  and got INT (1) 1

Comment: So now you can go back to the mysql_fetch_row() function

Comment: SOLVED IT :D

After trying everything suggested i started over and used the WHERE clause with the SELECT and printed result with echo $count[0];

:)

Comment: So... That's actually what I suggested. Well good you got it working now :)

Comment: lol thanks... i just needed to sort out all the suggestions and ake it correct :P

Any idea how to make the views count only once per session? i cant store IP's, well i can but if it is an easier way maybe?

Should i make a new question for this?

Comment: I would store the article id's in an array in the user's session (using the $_SESSION variable). But if you can't get it to work, then yes you should start a new question.

Comment: @Ron http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342895/mysql-pageviews-update-only-per-session  :P

Answer (score 0):

`$count` is an `array`, not a scalar. Try `echo $count[];`

There is a set of techniques called `debugging` when things don't work as expected. The very first step you make is "divide and conquer" by separating complex expressions into simple ones:

```
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT count = count(post) FROM post");
if ($resource) {
    $count = mysql_fetch_row();
    if ($count > 0) {
       echo $count[0];
    } else {
       echo 'it seems that post table is empty';
    }
} else {
    echo 'I need to figure out what went wrong by looking in PHP documentation for mysql error query functions';
}
```

Secondly, when debugging, instead of `echo` use `var_dump($resource)` or `var_dump($count)`. That way you will see the real type and value of a variables.

PS. `mysql_query` is deprecated and might be removed from PHP in any future version

Comment: I've just read documentation on mysql_query. it returns NUMERICAL array. not associative. so it should not be $count['post'] but $count[0]

Answer (score 0):

`$count1` is an [Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php);
Try to `print` the result to view what's contain on your array like this:

```
print_r($count1);
```

If your array contains anything, it'll show up this way:

```
Array(
'key' => 'value'
)
```

To show result based on specific `key`, try this:

```
echo $count1['key'];
```

Comment: excuse me for being completely useless with this code, but could you please explain where to put this code? :P I tried to replace 
echo $count['count'];  with print_r($count1);


I now have this code:

mysql_query("UPDATE news SET post = post + 1, published=published, last_edit=last_edit WHERE id=$id");

$count1 = mysql_fetch_row(count("SELECT post FROM news")); var_dump($count1);  

print_r($count1);  ?>

All get is bool(false)

Comment: sorry for not marking code, but couldnt even figure that out :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace

```
$count1 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT post FROM post"));
```

with

```
$count1 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT count = count(post) FROM news"));
```

and then `echo $count1['count'];`