# Mysql Pageviews update only per session

Tags: php, mysql

just got help with making my code for pageviews work... and now i would like the pageviews only count 1 for each session / ip.

In my **users** (news.users) table i have these cells available for use: (tried to set up something earlier that didnt work out so these are not in use)

```
ip_reg, ip_visit, dtreg, dtvisit, visits, pass
```

The code i have that is now working looks like this :

```
//Adds one to the counter 

  mysql_query("UPDATE news SET posts = posts + 1, published=published, last_edit=last_edit WHERE id=$id");

//Retreives the current count 
$count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT posts FROM news WHERE id=$id"));
//Displays the count on your site print 


echo "<label>Viewed: ";
echo $count[0];
echo " times</label>";

?>
```

Can i use some of the unused cells in users to stop a user from reloading the page to get higher views on a page?  And how do i do it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I suggested I would put the read news articles in the user's session. Try this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['read_news']) || !is_array($_SESSION['read_news'])) {
    $_SESSION['read_news'] = array();
}

if (!in_array($id, $_SESSION['read_news'])) {
    $_SESSION['read_news'][] = $id;
    mysql_query("UPDATE news SET posts = posts + 1 WHERE id=$id");
}
```

If this doesn't work, you don't have sessions enabled and you should put `session_start();` somewhere in the top of your project. Make sure that line is called in each request.

Comment: noob question again....  the 'read_news' you are reffering to, is this a cell? :P

Comment: can i use cookies?   in my user.inc file i have this line:

 
' global $USER_COOKIE,$_COOKIE,$COOKIE_KEY;



    $this->is_anonymous = 0;



    $cookie = $_COOKIE[$USER_COOKIE];



    if (isset($COOKIE_KEY)) {'

Comment: No, it's a key in the superglobal `$_SESSION` variable. `$_SESSION` is just an array where you can store information related to the user's session. When you call `print_r($_SESSION);` you can see what's in there. When you add a value to the `$_SESSION` array (e.g. `$_SESSION[] = 'foo';`) and hit refresh, it should still be in the array.

Comment: When i call print_r($SESSION) i got this result:

''Array ( [read_news] => Array ( [0] => 120037 ) )  ''

120037 is the page id

Comment: No, you can name 'read_news' whatever you want. The point is that you build an array of news post's ids that the user has read. Before you increase the counter, you check whether that id is in the array. If not, you count a new view and add the post id to the 'read_news' array. Otherwise you do nothing, because the user visits that article for the 2nd (or more) time

Comment: Make sure you use `print_r($_SESSION)` in stead of `print_r($SESSION)`. Now when you visit another post you should see two ids (120037 and the one you visit then)

Comment: ok, but i dont really understand where this is stored... doesnt the users news posts ids need to be stored somewhere?

Comment: i only see one id, of the page i visit... and when i refresh it still counts every time

Comment: It is stored, in the user's session on the server. You can see `$_SESSION` as a server side cookie. It's stored on the server and is user specific. If it doesn't work, you don't call `session_start();` anywhere in your code.

Comment: hmm... added session_start(); and got some strange info...

i have an ad script on my site from a company named softbiz and this was returned now:

Array ( [softbiz_banad_removedname] => admin [softbiz_banad_removeid] => 1 [read_news] => Array ( [0] => 120037 ) )

Comment: Well just don't worry about that too much. Is it working when you go to another post?

Comment: yes, now it list up the post ids
(but still counts every time i refresh)

Comment: Make sure you deleted the `mysql_query("UPDATE news SET posts = posts + 1, published=published, last_edit=last_edit WHERE id=$id");` line

Comment: Please marry me :P 
thanks a lot... everything works fine now.
And thank you for being patient again with my noob knowledge :)